# How to parse this data provided by python?

Tags: python, node.js, linux, go, format

I have program written in Python - [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/).
It is a modern journal being saved on my PC locally in text files with this format:

`$ cat ~/.rednotebook/data/2016-01.txt`

gives me something like this:

```
10: {text: плов}
11: {text: '#переход

    Легли около часа

    Встали около 12 часов'}
12: {text: '{}

''

''{

''}

\''

\{

\}'}
```

Note that format looks like json, but with single quotes `'` instead of double quotes, it has integers as primary keys(?) to indicate the day in month. And it escapes special characters by prepending `'` single quote.

So, my question is this:

**How does this format of data is called?**

Are there any libraries for parsing this format in Nodejs or Golang?

UPD1: i have found this post [How to merge two versions of RedNotebook](https://answers.launchpad.net/rednotebook/+question/254990)
They say -

> it's quite easy to mess up the YAML markup that is used in the month
> files, but RedNotebook will issue a warning when it sees such a file
> and you can fix it.

I'll try to parse it as yaml code

Comment: It is in the format RedNotebook saves it in, it is its own format, so you have to figure out how to parse it yourself

Comment: Were you working on an webapp version of the awesome tool?

Comment: no, cli tool to import data into *sql database for some research and for fast full text seach in ~ 15mb rednotebook logs i gathered in few years :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned to be the YAML code.
It can be parsed by https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml